# Pandas df row count

Tags: pandas

```
         Date  Ct
0  2015-04-01   1
1  2015-04-01   2
2  2015-04-01   3
3  2015-04-01   4
4  2015-04-02   1
5  2015-04-02   2
6  2015-04-02   3
7  2015-04-02   4
8  2015-04-03   1
9  2015-04-03   2
10 2015-04-03   3
11 2015-04-03   4
12 2015-04-04   1
13 2015-04-04   2
14 2015-04-04   3
15 2015-04-04   4
```

I have a string column 'Date' and I would like to create the 'Ct' column as represented below to maintain a count of the rows for a certain date.  Date needs to be a string in my application,  there will not always be an equal number of rows for each date, and 'Ct' will always count in the order of the numerical index.  An answer or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check out `df.groupby`

Comment: but make another column with dates as date... also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is a little weird but you can add a temp column and set this value to 1:

```
df['temp'] = 1
```

you can then perform a groupby on 'Date' and call `transform` on the 'temp' column to perform the count:

```
In [80]:

df['Ct'] = df.groupby('Date')['temp'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
df
Out[80]:
         Date  temp  Ct
0  2015-04-01     1   1
1  2015-04-01     1   2
2  2015-04-01     1   3
3  2015-04-01     1   4
4  2015-04-02     1   1
5  2015-04-02     1   2
6  2015-04-02     1   3
7  2015-04-02     1   4
8  2015-04-03     1   1
9  2015-04-03     1   2
10 2015-04-03     1   3
11 2015-04-03     1   4
12 2015-04-04     1   1
13 2015-04-04     1   2
14 2015-04-04     1   3
15 2015-04-04     1   4
In [81]:

df.drop('temp',axis=1,inplace=True)
df
Out[81]:
         Date  Ct
0  2015-04-01   1
1  2015-04-01   2
2  2015-04-01   3
3  2015-04-01   4
4  2015-04-02   1
5  2015-04-02   2
6  2015-04-02   3
7  2015-04-02   4
8  2015-04-03   1
9  2015-04-03   2
10 2015-04-03   3
11 2015-04-03   4
12 2015-04-04   1
13 2015-04-04   2
14 2015-04-04   3
15 2015-04-04   4
```

The reason we can't just say perform the `cumsum` on the 'Date' column is because if it's a string then this will result in your date strings being concatenated with each other which is not what you want.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the master @Jeff for pointing out that the temp columns is unncecessary and you just use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount)

```
In [150]:

df['Ct'] = df.groupby('Date').cumcount() + 1
df
Out[150]:
          Date  Ct
0   2015-04-01   1
1   2015-04-01   2
2   2015-04-01   3
3   2015-04-01   4
4   2015-04-02   1
5   2015-04-02   2
6   2015-04-02   3
7   2015-04-02   4
8   2015-04-03   1
9   2015-04-03   2
10  2015-04-03   3
11  2015-04-03   4
12  2015-04-04   1
13  2015-04-04   2
14  2015-04-04   3
15  2015-04-04   4
```

Comment: cumcount() does exactly this